# Highcharts: Handling ng-click on tooltips

Tags: angular, highcharts, tooltip

I need some help with a problem I am encountering. I created a chart and a custom tooltip, whenever the user clicks on the tooltip, it should call the $scope function.

```
        tooltip: {
            pointFormatter: function() {
              return $compile(angular.element("<p style='color:red' ng-click='handleClick()'>Click here</p>"))(scope);
            }
        }
```

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4WHbv/683/) for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile the tooltip element after the tooltip appears.

In the pointFormatter return string:

```
pointFormatter: function() {              
  return "<p style='color:red' ng-click='handleClick()'>Click here</p>"
}
```

In the click callback:

```
events: {
  click: function(e) {
    tooltip.refresh(e.point, e);
    $compile(tooltip.label.div)(scope)
  }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/mj9mj1n5/

Comment: If the tool tip has quite a lot going on functionality wise and styling, is it possible to render a component into here would you know?