# adding ng-click attribute on highcharts tooltip

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I'm trying to add an ng-click attribute in the return of my formatter object in highcharts:

```
formatter: function() {
 var item = "";
 if (this.series.name == fluidVsConsumerDaily.pondSelection.pondName) {
     item = angular.element('<a> Pond Volume Level: <b>' + this.y + '(BBL)</b></a>');
 } else {
     item = angular.element('<button ng-click="vCtrl.section.dashboard.fluidVsConsumerDaily.openFluidSourceModal(' + this.series.options.fluidSourceFacilityId + ')"> Fluid Source: <b>' + this.series.options.fluidSourceName + '</b> - ' + this.y + '(BBL) </button>');
 }
 var element = $compile(item)(vm);
 $scope.$digest();
 return element.html();
},
```

Unfortunately the click still doesn't work. When i'm inspecting the DOM, ng-click is present.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: vm is my scope. sorry didn't mentioned that.

Comment: Check [Highcharts: Handling ng-click on tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44910773/2435473)