# Launch click event from tooltip highcharts

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, ionic2, ionic3

I want to launch an event when clicking on the tooltip of highcharts.
I'm using highcharts in Ionic/Angular project.
Here is an example:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Tooltip footer format demo'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'The tooltip should provide a HTML table where the table is closed in the footerFormat'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true,
        pointFormat: '<button onclick="launchEvent()"></button>',
        valueDecimals: 2
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Short',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        name: 'Long named series',
        data: [129.9, 171.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 195.6, 154.4].reverse()
    }]

});
```

The problem is that when I use the code below I get an error saying that `launchEvent()` doesn't exist in the page, which is not correct because it does exit. This led me to think that the method should be defined with a Highchart's method.
Any ideas, please? I want to have a click event inside the tooltip.

Comment: This SO thread should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44907719/highcharts-handling-ng-click-on-tooltips.